# How to send a multipart request with only one json field?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to send a multipart request with one field but I cannot find it in the logs. My code is

```
Feature: test

Scenario: test send

Given url 'https://apitester.com/api/send'
And multipart field myJson = {test:'send'}
When method post
Then status 200
```

but in the logs I find only

```
1 > POST https://apitester.com/api/send
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 226
1 > Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=57Gy9v3RTbI82kmdNf-nsWld3wK1rz6W99F
1 > Host: apitester.com
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/14.0.1)
```

In Postman I get something like this and it's working fine:

```
POST /api/send HTTP/1.1
Host: apitester.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myJson"

{"test":"send"}
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

If I add `And header Content-Type = 'application/json'` it gets somehow similar but it's not working either:

```
1 > POST https://apitester.com/api/send
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 218
1 > Content-Type: application/json; boundary=bzLjH96ptD4G7HSRWI65XMnIhllxtiO
1 > Host: apitester.com
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/14.0.1)
--bzLjH96ptD4G7HSRWI65XMnIhllxtiO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myJson"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{"test":"send"}
--bzLjH96ptD4G7HSRWI65XMnIhllxtiO--
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the `Content-Type` is not "printable" (e.g. binary) Karate doesn't log it.

On troubleshooting, this can be difficult, but if you work with your server-side folks you should be able to figure it out sooner. If you post a cURL command that works, the community here can help you.

We'll improve the logging in future versions.

Comment: Logging the request I get

    `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`

Is there a way to edit these headers for each multipart field?

Comment: @Leonardo you can try `multipart file` - doesn't need to be a file, and you can control the `Content-Type` https://github.com/intuit/karate#multipart-file